# Xcode performance issue when compiling Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I have run app on simulator, then stop it and then I clicked Run button one more time.

I have not modified any files in the project just rerun it. But it takes the same time for compiling Swift files even in case I already built a project (5 - 7 mins).

What can be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Hit Run button then,

1. Goto "Report Navigator", within left panel of Xcode,

[image]

2. Select current build,

[image]

3. After selecting, within center panel you can see files getting complied one by one and you can identify which particular file is taking long time for compiling.

[image]

---

Or else if you wish to know, which particular function in your code is taking long time, I will advice you to go [here](http://irace.me/swift-profiling).

Comment: ok got it thanks for help, by some reason it happens not all time so sometimes it stuck, but sometimes not )